# How to show image dynamycally in html(angularjs)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, src

```
 src={{logo}}

var logo = 'localhost:3000/modules/images/default.png'
```

I am displaying the image path dynamicaly but its not showing path in html, 
Do i need to use quotes for src?Can anyone please help me.

Comment: For quotes:- <figure>
  <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
  <figcaption>Fig.1 - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
</figure>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

```
<img ng-src="{{logoUrl}}">
```

This gives you expected result, because **phone.imageUrl is evaluated and replaced by its value after angular is loaded**.

```
<img src="{{logoUrl}}">
```

But with this, the browser tries to load an image named {{phone.imageUrl}}, which results in a failed request. You can check this in the console of your browser.

```js
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.logo='https://angularjs.org/img/AngularJS-large.png';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div>
    <img ng-src="{{logo}}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not getting the image displayed with the abovee code.

Comment: @nlr_p that was localhost URL(Accessible only from your system). I have added other URL which is accessible. Please check

Comment: @nir_p You can check the output in the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img ng-src={{logo}}/>

$scope.logo = 'localhost:3000/modules/images/default.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use ng-src..

```
$scope.logo = 'localhost:3000/modules/images/default.png';

 <img ng-src="{{logo}}">
```